# PHP. Is there a way to require a function parameter to be an array?

Tags: php, function, parameters

Is there a way to require a function parameter is a specific datatype such as an array? For instance something like this:

```
function example(array $array){}
```

If so does that work for all datatypes? Is there a good resource that would show me how to do this?

Comment: Not for all, but for Array and Types (classes/interfaces). You find that documented in the manual. Please do your homework first and look in there, it answers your question with much more detail.

Comment: http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/#functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: Yes, you can type-hint with arrays, so edited my answer and changed accordingly.**

What you want to do is called [type-hinting](http://php.net/language.oop5.typehinting.php). You can't type hint basic data types, such as `int`, `string`, `bool`. You can type-hint with `array` or objects and interfaces:

```
function example_hinted1(array $arr) {

}

function example_hinted2(User $user) {

}
```

Calling `example_hinted1(5)` will generate a PHP fatal error (not an exception), but calling it passing an array is totally ok.

If you need to be sure that some argument to a function is from a basic type you can simulate this behavior with code inside your function:

```
function example($number) {
  if (!is_int($number) {
    throw new Exception("You must pass an integer to ".__FUNCTION__."()");
  }
  // rest of your function
}
```

So, these snippets would work:

```
example(1);

$b = 5 + 8;
example($b);
```

while these would throw an exception:

```
example('foo');
example(array(5, 6));
example(new User());
```

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer it helped a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at Type hinting http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php